# Android Studio HiDPI support for Linux

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1, android-studio-2.2, hidpi

I'm struggling with HiDPI support of Android Studio 2.1.3 for Linux Mint. What I know it should be possible to enable Android Studio's HiDPI support  by adding `-Dhidpi=true` flag to `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions` Unfortunately it doesn't change anything on my machine, the UI is still very small.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I did not manage to "enable" hidpi for Android Studio.

Therefore, I run Android Studio like so:

```
$ xrandr --dpi 192; android-studio&
```

Or whatever you prefer instead of `192`, of course.

Comment: Worked fine with 2.1.3 and 2.2. Thank you, great answer!

Comment: That's a wonderful tip: can't believe I never thought to set DPI on a per-process basis.

Comment: You deserve a medal my friend!

Comment: For me on an XPS (I think it has a 4K resolution) I had to use `xrandr --dpi 288` to fix the scaling, otherwise most (but not all) elements were not scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2.3 has HiDPI support out of the box

Comment: It should have HiDPI support since 2.1 but it doesn't work without workarounds, like the one provided by JonesV